# tableHeaderView is blank after reloadingRows

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView where i am setting the `tableHeaderView`. Working and showing fine. **(note that its not a section header)**

```
self.tableview.tableHeaderView = myCustomView;
```

When i execute the following lines of code the `tableHeaderView` goes blank leaving an empty space where it used to be.

```
[tableView beginUpdates];

//update the view for which the button was clicked
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
NSArray *indexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

[tableView endUpdates];
```

what gives?

Comment: you need to show more code like headerForSection

Comment: I am not using the headerForSection delegate methods. I don't want headers for sections. I have a tableHeader. Apple specifically mentions in the docs that they are not the same

Comment: sorry I got confused, but why dont you reset that header again  after the code `self.tableview.tableHeaderView = myCustomView;`